# Linker error with glew when library is statically linked

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries, glew

I am trying to build an opengl project in Visual Studio 2012. I wanted to statically include glew library, so I built it from source and copied the generated glew32sd.lib to my lib directory. I gave this lib path to Visual Studio and put "glew32sd.lib" to my additional dependencies in VS.

Now when I compile a sample code in main.cpp:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include<GL/glew.h>
int main(){
    glewInit();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>glew32sd.lib(glew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetString@4 referenced in function _glewGetExtension@4
1>glew32sd.lib(glew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetCurrentDC@0 referenced in function _wglewInit@0
1>glew32sd.lib(glew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4 referenced in function _wglewInit@0
1>C:\Projects\OpenGL\opengl\Debug\opengl.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

In my understanding, this error should be because compiler could not find the definitions for the function call.

Here are a few relevant snapshots:
[The Library dependencies of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBl4h.png)

[Path to libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmzME.png)

Why could this error be coming? I tried rebuilding the solution but that didn't help either. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in the linker settings:

- You can link against the statically linked version of glew or the dynamically linked one, but never against both. So if you want glew statically linked remove `glew32d.lib` (or `glew32.lib` in release mode) from the additional dependencies.
- Glew requires you to also link agains the opengl library. Add `OpenGL32.lib` to the additional dependencies.